# Not Able To Connect To Webservice With Android

Tags: android, .net, android-ndk

**Not Able To Connect To Webservice With Android
it not acess the webservice code** 
i have tried to make thread and then run my code there 
i test the webservice link from my phone , its reachable

here are the code both .net and android :-

Webservice Code .net :**strong text**

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
Public Class Service
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As Integer
        Return 0
    End Function

End Class
```

Here Is the Code

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

    ImageButton btn1;
    ImageButton Save;
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
    private static final String MethodName = "HelloWorld";
    private static final String NameSpace = "http://tempuri.org/"; 
    private static final String URL = "http://172.20.10.2/WebSite9/Service.asmx";  
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         final Thread webser    = new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                try {
                  //  String project = titles.get(position - 1);

               //     CallWebService();
                 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NameSpace, MethodName);         
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                   envelope.dotNet=true; 

                   // request.addProperty("TextToDisplay", "This is coming from android");
                 envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); 

                  androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); 

                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); 
                 //   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                  Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());

                }


            }

        };
        webser.start();
```

please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code Seems to be ok

please make sure that : -

1- use ksoap2-android-2.5.2.jar
2- go to buildpath>add external jars and select it
3- copy the ksoap2-android-2.5.2.jar and paste it under libs file

restart the application and try ?

Answer (score 0):

put this code:

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

instead of this

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

and it will work with you as expected.